# MPI_Igatherv received buffers aren't filled with larger amounts of data sent

Tags: c++, mpi, race-condition

Disclaimer: I'm fairly new at MPI.

I'm implementing MPI on an existing application with the goal of having one rank that receives computed data from all the other ranks and writes it into a database.

We have an MPI driver that's called to run gather calls every N computing iterations, we want it to return it immediately so that the ranks can continue with their computation. In this function, I'm using the blocking `MPI_Gather` call to get the data buffer sizes and the non-blocking `MPI_Igatherv` call to gather the data. I call `MPI_Wait` immediately on the receiver rank and I call `MPI_Wait` before the next gather calls are made for the other ranks.

The problem I'm running into is that the buffers appear to not be filling in before I read it on the receiver rank when there is a large amount of data. This seems like a race condition problem to me but I thought the `MPI_Wait` calls would take care of it. I've also tried `MPI_Test` for the non-receiving ranks but that also didn't work. Everything is sent and received properly when I change to use `MPI_Gatherv` instead.

My questions would be:

- Is there some sort of limitation on buffer sizes that's sent in non-blocking calls?
- Am I using `MPI_Wait` properly?
- Am I misunderstanding how to use MPI for this problem?

Below is a reproducible code, I've set `nDataSize` to be 10000 and the output logs show this:

```
First value from process 0: 90.
First value from process 1: -842150451.
First value from process 2: 835060048.
```

If `nDataSize = 100`, the output log shows the correct values:

```
First value from process 0: 90.
First value from process 1: 99.
First value from process 2: 108.
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#include "mpi.h"

int main( int iNumArgs, char** azArgs )
{
    MPI_Init( &iNumArgs, &azArgs );

    // Get number of processes and check only 3 processes are used
    int nRanks;
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nRanks );
    if ( nRanks != 3 )
    {
        printf( "This application is meant to be run with 3 processes.\n" );
        MPI_Abort( MPI_COMM_WORLD, EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // Get my rank
    int                                     my_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank );

    // Rank to receive (gather) the data:
    int                                     iReceiverRank                       = 0;
    auto                                    xIsReceiverRank                     = [&my_rank, &iReceiverRank]() -> bool
    {
        return my_rank == iReceiverRank;
    };

    // Part of our MPI driver properties:
    bool                                    bGatherStarted                      = false;
    MPI_Request                             gatherRequest;

    int                                     nIterations                         = 10;

    // !! CHANGE THIS TO REPRODUCE
    int                                     nDataSize                           = 10000;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < nIterations; ++i )
    {
        // Work takes around 100-200ms
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 200 ) );

        if ( bGatherStarted )
        {
            MPI_Wait( &gatherRequest, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );
            printf( "Process %d: Finished waiting for gather request.\n", my_rank );
        }

        // Create our data to be gathered:
        std::stringstream                   stream;
        int                                 my_value                            = int( i + 1 ) * ( 10 + my_rank );
        for ( int j = 0; j < nDataSize; ++j )
        {
            int                             iVal                                = my_value + j;
            stream.write( reinterpret_cast<const char*>( &iVal ), sizeof( int ) );
        }

        // Double the size for next iteration:
        nDataSize = nDataSize + 1;

        std::string                         zBuffer                             = stream.str();

        int*                                rcounts                             = NULL;
        int                                 iSendBufferSize                     = (int)zBuffer.size();

        if ( xIsReceiverRank() )
        {
            rcounts = new int[nRanks];
        }

        MPI_Gather( &iSendBufferSize, 1, MPI_INT, rcounts, 1, MPI_INT, iReceiverRank, MPI_COMM_WORLD );

        if ( xIsReceiverRank() )
        {
            // Received buffer, total buffer length, displacements:
            char*                           rbuf                                = NULL;
            int                             iRecvBufferSize                     = 0;
            int*                            displs                              = new int[nRanks];

            displs[0] = 0;
            iRecvBufferSize += rcounts[0];
            printf( "Process %d: Rank %d: count = %d, displs: = %d\n", my_rank, 0, rcounts[0], displs[0] );

            for ( int r = 1; r < nRanks; ++r )
            {
                iRecvBufferSize += rcounts[r];
                displs[r] = displs[r - 1] + rcounts[r - 1];

                printf( "Process %d: Rank %d: count = %d, displs: = %d\n", my_rank, r, rcounts[r], displs[r] );
            }

            iRecvBufferSize += 1;
            rbuf = new char[iRecvBufferSize];
            rbuf[iRecvBufferSize - 1] = '\0'; // null terminate the char buffer

            // Gather all buffers:
            MPI_Igatherv( zBuffer.c_str(), iSendBufferSize, MPI_CHAR, rbuf, rcounts, displs, MPI_CHAR, iReceiverRank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &gatherRequest );
            MPI_Wait( &gatherRequest, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );

            // We pass it out in a custom stream class that wraps a stringstream but for the sake of this, we'll just put it into a vector of strings:
            std::vector<std::string>    out_Streams;

            // Process the received data:
            int                             iCount                              = 0;
            for ( int r = 0; r < nRanks; ++r )
            {
                std::stringstream           stream;
                stream.write( rbuf, rcounts[r] );
                out_Streams.push_back( stream.str() );

                // For checking the data that's been received:
                int                         test;
                stream.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>( &test ), sizeof( int ) );
                printf( "First value from process %d: %d.\n", r, test );

                rbuf += rcounts[r];
                iCount += rcounts[r];
            }

            // Reset pointer to the beginning:
            rbuf -= iCount;

            delete[] rcounts;
            delete[] displs;
            delete[] rbuf;
        }
        else
        {
            // Send buffer (non-blocking):
            MPI_Igatherv( zBuffer.c_str(), iSendBufferSize, MPI_CHAR, NULL, NULL, NULL, MPI_CHAR, iReceiverRank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &gatherRequest );

            if ( i == ( nIterations - 1 ) )
            {
                // Last iteration, call wait now:
                MPI_Wait( &gatherRequest, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );
            }
            else
            {
                int                         iGatherComplete                     = 0;
                MPI_Test( &gatherRequest, &iGatherComplete, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );
                if ( !iGatherComplete )
                {
                    bGatherStarted = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT

After doing some more testing, I realized that the limitation to buffer size for each rank is exactly 1024 integers, or 4mb. Total buffer size would be 12mb.

I found this paper on scaling issues: [http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~hli035/publications/papers/scaling_hips18_hli.pdf](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Ehli035/publications/papers/scaling_hips18_hli.pdf). I'm not sure if it's relevant because from my understanding the scaling issues are happening for Igatherv at 44 ranks, 44mb each and the displacement values don't appear to be corrupted.

Comment: Do your receivers ever wait for the Igatherv request?

Comment: yup, I call MPI_Wait right after MPI_Igatherv on the receiver rank.

Comment: Sorry, I meant *non*-receivers.

Comment: the MPI part looks ok. you send `1011121314...` so `stream >> test;` results in several integer overflows. I guess you meant to `stream << ( my_value + j ) << " "; when populating `zBuffer`.

Comment: note you should always `MPI_Wait()` a request when you do not need it anymore (at least to give MPI a chance to do some cleanup and free some resources. So you'd rather unconditionally `MPI_Wait()` on the non root ranks at the end of the iteration (and you won't miss the last `MPI_Igatherv()`)

Comment: @VictorEijkhout yup, I do it at the beginning of every iteration before the next set of gathers are called. there's a flag to make sure it's not called when there isn't a gather request in progress.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I actually meant to do `stream.write( reinterpret_cast<const char*>( &iVal ), sizeof( int ) );` and `stream.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>( &test ), sizeof( int ) );` but had forgotten to update the code ):

Ah I completely missed that bit of logic with missing the last `MPI_Igatherv()` call, thanks! The application iterates through its computation and at the end of every iteration it's sending the data off to a db writer instance and continuing on to the next iteration once that returns. The code is edited to fix the stream and the last iteration, problem is still there..

Comment: you still do not `MPI_Wait()` all your requests. fwiw, you also never reset `bGatherStarted`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet oh is it because of the `MPI_Test()` call? I assumed, perhaps incorrectly, that I don't need to call `MPI_Wait()` if `MPI_Test()` has a complete flag set.

Comment: right, you should not assume `MPI_Test()` is enough.